# In my client server code I am able to do telnet to server with the Ipaddress I got through the ifconfig?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, ubuntu-11.04

But when I use the same Ipaddress to connect to server through my client code it gives connection recieve 
connect() failed: Connection refused.
I wished to check the server Ipaddress through getsockname().The ipaddress I received is

Address is '0.0.0.0:9000'
I used this 
I am a biggner programmer using Oracle Virtual box environment (Ubuntu )
Please Clarify which ipaddress I should use to pass to Client to coonect to server 
Usage : ./ 
Usage : ./  <"String">
I am basically trying to make an echo server .
Thanks in advance .
Client Code :
    #include "Practical.h"

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {



if (argc < 3 || argc > 4) // Test for correct number of arguments
    DieWithUserMessage("Parameter(s)",
        "<Server Address> <Echo Word> [<Server Port>]");

  char *servIP = argv[1];     // First arg: server IP address (dotted quad)
  char *echoString = argv[2]; // Second arg: string to echo

  // Third arg (optional): server port (numeric).  7 is well-known echo port
  in_port_t servPort = (argc == 4) ? atoi(argv[3]) : 7;

  // Create a reliable, stream socket using TCP
  int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  if (sock < 0)
    DieWithSystemMessage("socket() failed");

  // Construct the server address structure
  struct sockaddr_in servAddr;            // Server address
  memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr)); // Zero out structure
  servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;          // IPv4 address family
  // Convert address
  int rtnVal = inet_pton(AF_INET, servIP, &servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
  if (rtnVal == 0)
    DieWithUserMessage("inet_pton() failed", "invalid address string");
  else if (rtnVal < 0)
    DieWithSystemMessage("inet_pton() failed");
  servAddr.sin_port = htons(servPort);    // Server port
    printf ("Hello");

  // Establish the connection to the echo server
  if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) < 0)
    DieWithSystemMessage("connect() failed");

  size_t echoStringLen = strlen(echoString); // Determine input length

  // Send the string to the server
  ssize_t numBytes = send(sock, echoString, echoStringLen, 0);
  if (numBytes < 0)
    DieWithSystemMessage("send() failed");
  else if (numBytes != echoStringLen)
    DieWithUserMessage("send()", "sent unexpected number of bytes");

  // Receive the same string back from the server
  unsigned int totalBytesRcvd = 0; // Count of total bytes received
  fputs("Received: ", stdout);     // Setup to print the echoed string
  while (totalBytesRcvd < echoStringLen) {
    char buffer[BUFSIZE]; // I/O buffer
    /* Receive up to the buffer size (minus 1 to leave space for
     a null terminator) bytes from the sender */
    numBytes = recv(sock, buffer, BUFSIZE - 1, 0);
    if (numBytes < 0)
      DieWithSystemMessage("recv() failed");
    else if (numBytes == 0)
      DieWithUserMessage("recv()", "connection closed prematurely");
    totalBytesRcvd += numBytes; // Keep tally of total bytes
    buffer[numBytes] = '\0';    // Terminate the string!
    fputs(buffer, stdout);      // Print the echo buffer
  }

  fputc('\n', stdout); // Print a final linefeed

  close(sock);
  exit(0);
}

Server Code :
#define  BUFSIZE  512
void HandleTCPClient(int clntSocket) {
  char buffer[BUFSIZE]; // Buffer for echo string

  // Receive message from client
  ssize_t numBytesRcvd = recv(clntSocket, buffer, BUFSIZE, 0);
  if (numBytesRcvd < 0)
    printf("recv() failed");

  // Send received string and receive again until end of stream
  while (numBytesRcvd > 0) { // 0 indicates end of stream
    // Echo message back to client
    ssize_t numBytesSent = send(clntSocket, buffer, numBytesRcvd, 0);
    if (numBytesSent < 0)
      printf("send() failed");
    else if (numBytesSent != numBytesRcvd)
      printf("send()", "sent unexpected number of bytes");

    // See if there is more data to receive
    numBytesRcvd = recv(clntSocket, buffer, BUFSIZE, 0);
    if (numBytesRcvd < 0)
      printf("recv() failed");
  }

  close(clntSocket); // Close client socket
}
static const int MAXPENDING = 5;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  if (argc != 2)
  {
    printf ("Parameters , <Server Port required >");
  }
  in_port_t servPort = atoi(argv[1]);
  int servSock; // Socket descriptor for server
  if ((servSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
  {
    printf ( "Socket Failed ");
    exit (1);
  }
  struct sockaddr_in servAddr;                  // Local address
  memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));       // Zero out structure
  servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                // IPv4 address family
  servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); // Any incoming interface
  servAddr.sin_port = htons(servPort);          // Local port

  // Bind to the local address
  if (bind(servSock, (struct sockaddr*) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) < 0)
  {
    printf ("Bind Failed ");
    exit (1);
  }
  // Mark the socket so it will listen for incoming connections
  if (listen(servSock, MAXPENDING) < 0)
    printf("listen() failed");
   for (;;) { // Run forever
    struct sockaddr_in clntAddr; // Client address
    // Set length of client address structure (in-out parameter)
    socklen_t clntAddrLen = sizeof(clntAddr);

    // Wait for a client to connect
    int clntSock = accept(servSock, (struct sockaddr *) &clntAddr, &clntAddrLen);
    if (clntSock < 0)
      printf ("accept() failed");

    // clntSock is connected to a client!

    char clntName[INET_ADDRSTRLEN]; // String to contain client address
    if (inet_ntop(AF_INET, &clntAddr.sin_addr.s_addr, clntName,
        sizeof(clntName)) != NULL)
      printf("Handling client %s/%d\n", clntName, ntohs(clntAddr.sin_port));
    else
      puts("Unable to get client address");

    HandleTCPClient(clntSock);
  }
  // NOT REACHED
}

Code is not mine I have Copied for Practice
```

Comment: `0.0.0.0:9000` is not a valid IP address - can you show your ifconfig output on the server?

Comment: there are far too many unknowns in your scenario for an intelligent, succinct answer to be made; you need to go through basic network connectivity troubleshooting to make sure you can reach the virtual machine, show the code performing the bind/accept in the server, and then edit your post to add that information

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

Server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>

#define  BUFSIZE  512
void HandleTCPClient(int clntSocket) {
  char buffer[BUFSIZE]; // Buffer for echo string

  // Receive message from client
  ssize_t numBytesRcvd = recv(clntSocket, buffer, BUFSIZE, 0);
  if (numBytesRcvd < 0)
    printf("recv() failed");

  // Send received string and receive again until end of stream
  while (numBytesRcvd > 0) { // 0 indicates end of stream
    // Echo message back to client
    ssize_t numBytesSent = send(clntSocket, buffer, numBytesRcvd, 0);
    if (numBytesSent < 0)
      printf("send() failed");
    else if (numBytesSent != numBytesRcvd)
      printf("send(), sent unexpected number of bytes");

    // See if there is more data to receive
    numBytesRcvd = recv(clntSocket, buffer, BUFSIZE, 0);
    if (numBytesRcvd < 0)
      printf("recv() failed");
  }

  close(clntSocket); // Close client socket
}
static const int MAXPENDING = 5;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  if (argc != 2)
  {
    printf ("Parameters , <Server Port required >");
  }
  in_port_t servPort = atoi(argv[1]);
  int servSock; // Socket descriptor for server
  if ((servSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
  {
    printf ( "Socket Failed ");
    exit (1);
  }
  struct sockaddr_in servAddr;                  // Local address
  memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));       // Zero out structure
  servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                // IPv4 address family
  servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); // Any incoming interface
  servAddr.sin_port = htons(servPort);          // Local port

  // Bind to the local address
  if (bind(servSock, (struct sockaddr*) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) < 0)
  {
    printf ("Bind Failed ");
    exit (1);
  }
  // Mark the socket so it will listen for incoming connections
  if (listen(servSock, MAXPENDING) < 0)
    printf("listen() failed");
   for (;;) { // Run forever
    struct sockaddr_in clntAddr; // Client address
    // Set length of client address structure (in-out parameter)
    socklen_t clntAddrLen = sizeof(clntAddr);

    // Wait for a client to connect
    int clntSock = accept(servSock, (struct sockaddr *) &clntAddr, &clntAddrLen);
    if (clntSock < 0)
      printf ("accept() failed");

    // clntSock is connected to a client!

    char clntName[INET_ADDRSTRLEN]; // String to contain client address
    if (inet_ntop(AF_INET, &clntAddr.sin_addr.s_addr, clntName,
        sizeof(clntName)) != NULL)
      printf("Handling client %s/%d\n", clntName, ntohs(clntAddr.sin_port));
    else
      puts("Unable to get client address");

    HandleTCPClient(clntSock);
  }
  // NOT REACHED
}
```

Client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>

#define  BUFSIZE  512

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

if (argc < 3 || argc > 4) // Test for correct number of arguments
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Parameter(s), <Server Address> <Echo Word> [<Server Port>]\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

  char *servIP = argv[1];     // First arg: server IP address (dotted quad)
  char *echoString = argv[2]; // Second arg: string to echo

  // Third arg (optional): server port (numeric).  7 is well-known echo port
  in_port_t servPort = (argc == 4) ? atoi(argv[3]) : 7;

  // Create a reliable, stream socket using TCP
  int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  if (sock < 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "socket() failed\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // Construct the server address structure
  struct sockaddr_in servAddr;            // Server address
  memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr)); // Zero out structure
  servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;          // IPv4 address family
  // Convert address
  int rtnVal = inet_pton(AF_INET, servIP, &servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
  if (rtnVal == 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "inet_pton() failed, invalid address string\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  else if (rtnVal < 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "inet_pton() failed\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  servAddr.sin_port = htons(servPort);    // Server port
    printf ("Hello");

  // Establish the connection to the echo server
  if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) < 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "connect() failed\n");

  size_t echoStringLen = strlen(echoString); // Determine input length
  // Send the string to the server
  ssize_t numBytes = send(sock, echoString, echoStringLen, 0);
  if (numBytes < 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "send() failed\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  else if (numBytes != echoStringLen)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "send(), sent unexpected number of bytes\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // Receive the same string back from the server
  unsigned int totalBytesRcvd = 0; // Count of total bytes received
  fputs("Received: ", stdout);     // Setup to print the echoed string
  while (totalBytesRcvd < echoStringLen) {
    char buffer[BUFSIZE]; // I/O buffer
    /* Receive up to the buffer size (minus 1 to leave space for
     a null terminator) bytes from the sender */
    numBytes = recv(sock, buffer, BUFSIZE - 1, 0);
    if (numBytes < 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "recv() failed\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (numBytes == 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "recv(), connection closed prematurely\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    totalBytesRcvd += numBytes; // Keep tally of total bytes
    buffer[numBytes] = '\0';    // Terminate the string!
    fputs(buffer, stdout);      // Print the echo buffer
    }

  fputc('\n', stdout); // Print a final linefeed

  close(sock);
  exit(0);
}
```

And you test like this (2 terminals):

```
toc@UnixServer:~./client_error_socket 192.168.1.7 "HELLO" 4444
HelloReceived: HELLO

toc@UnixServer:~./server_error_socket 4444
Handling client 192.168.1.7/56963
```

Use your ip address instead of (192.168.1.7).

Hope this help.

Regards.

Comment: Hi , I am using Oracle Virtual box Ubuntu .The Ipaddress which I get after ifconfig hope I am right .Do I have to make any change in Ubuntu configuration .

Comment: @Vivek : It does not change anything, you must use your ip address (by default VirtualBox give you a private ip address, something like : 192.168.x.x or 10.x.x.x or 172.16.x.x), so check the output of the command ifconfig and grub your address you can find an example of ifconfig here (http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/ifconfig-7-examples-to-configure-network-interface/)